# How to render simple text with br tag?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I have a simple component:

```
class News extends Component {
  state = { 
     isSimple: this.props.isSimple
  }
  render() { 
    return (
      <div>
        <div className="extended">extended</div>
        simple text
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default News;
```

I would like to display only either extended or simple, so I do:

```
class News extends Component {
  state = { 
    isSimple: this.props.isSimple
 }
  render() { 
    var text;
    if (this.state.isSimple) {
      text = "simple <br /> text";
    } else {
      text = <div className="extended">extended</div>
    }
    return (
      {text}
    );
  }
}
```

But if state isSimple = true then this show me:

```
simple <br /> text
```

instead of:

```
simple
text
```

Besides, it is not very legible. Can I make an if condition in the middle of the render method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why you need to save text and return it? instead return jsx statement, and instead of using if statement, use operators. something like:

```
class News extends Component {
  state = { 
    isSimple: this.props.isSimple
  }
  render() {
    const { isSimple } = this.state;
    return (
       { isSimple ? <div>simple <br /> text</div>
       : <div className="extended">extended</div>
       }
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap the string in an object with `{__html: 'your string here..'}` and then use it using [`dangerouslySetInnerHTML`](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml) props:

```
render() {
  var text;

  if (this.state.isSimple) {
    text = <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: "simple <br /> text" }} />;
  } else {
    text = <div className="extended">extended</div>;
  }
  return text;
}
```

[Fragments doesn't support dangerouslySetInnerHTML](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/12014), so I had to use `div` there.

```js
class News extends React.Component {
  state = {
    isSimple: this.props.isSimple
  };
render() {
  var text;

  if (this.state.isSimple) {
    text = <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: "simple <br /> text" }} />;
  } else {
    text = <div className="extended">extended</div>;
  }
  return text;
}
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<News isSimple={true} />, rootElement);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your are missing the return part of the render methods

```
render() { 
    var text;
    if (this.state.isSimple) {
      return <div>simple <br /> text</div>;
    } else {
      return <div className="extended">extended</div>;
    }
  }
```